# Remove file from repository

Tags: git

I have very interesting problem.

I have .gitignore file which came with cloning repo, first commit I didn't touch it, so everything was OK.
In second commit i added few lines to it and my commit can't go through QA because .gitignore shouldn't be there, but if I remove it with `git rm .gitignore --cached` it will be deleted from production server which is something what can't happen.

Is there a way to remove it from tracking but keep in repo without commiting in changes? and I need to edit last commit to do this.

Comment: Just delete (or edit) it and don't add the .gitignore to your commit stage. It's a bit of a pain in the rear probably, but the right solution is that it shouldn't be there at all if not truly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

3 options

1. add .gitignore to your .gitignore file
2. when you commit don't do `git commit -am` and only add the files that you need to commit
3. add the file patterns you want to ignore to `.git/info/exclude`, this isn't a tracked file but works the same as .gitignore

Comment: and what about editing previos commit? how can I remove it from there?
I have .gitignore file already commited and few others I want to remove

Comment: If it hasn't been pushed you can `git reset --soft` to a particular commit and then recommit your changes.  see [git reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) for more info.  Stack overflow has lots of answers for how do I undo a commit, etc.

Comment: it is pushed to gerrit

Comment: If you have pushed your changes to Gerrit, you have two choices: You can (a) abandon the existing change in Gerrit and push a new one, or (b) update the existing change in Gerrit by pushing a new change with the same Gerrit Change-Id.